# Express.js Not letting me handle errors: Exception has occurred: Error _runMicrotasks();

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

So I'm querying the Blizzard API Battle.Net for some information, character name and the realm they're in. Ofcourse it's possible for a user to query for a character that Does Not Exist, so Blizzard throws a 404 back to me and my server.js file doesn't know what to do with it even though I put something in place to handle it.

Releveant server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const blizzard = require('blizzard.js').initialize({apikey: "dummy"});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Source'));

//Listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Launch successful. To access app, open your browser and insert the following URL into your address bar: http://localhost:3000/");
});


app.post('/buttonpress', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: req.body.realm.name, name: req.body.name })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status != 200){
            res.send("That character doesn't exist! Please enter a valid character name.");
        } else {
            console.log(response.data);
            res.send(response.data);
        }
    });
});
```

I attempt to handle anything that's not a 200 by sending something to the client to tell the user: Character DNE!, but instead vscode gives me some red error codes mentioned in the title of this post (in vscode debugger anyway).

When I try this from a command line, just running `node server.js`, nothing happens when I click the Search Button. I've set breakpoints and it looks like the function doesn't get a response from the server. So the 404 is happening no matter what but I can't figure out how to handle it.

Answer (score -2):

Try placing your `app.listen` below/after your `app.post` Express.js runs in a middleware functionality so your listen is blocking all preceding code.

Comment: This isn't correct. [`listen()` is provided by the Node Core API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen) and has nothing to do with the middleware stack provided by Express. Once `listen()` is called, the socket  will begin to listen on the specified address and port for incoming connections. Doing this will not block any route handlers defined after `listen()`.

Comment: @peteb Awesome, thanks for the clarification. If you can provide and answer to this issue then it would be helpful. Thanks.